# Как правильно прописать код PHP в javascript-файл

Tags: php, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно прописать код PHP в файл javascript.
Вот честь кода javascript:

```
        var tickerContainer = $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('ticker-wrapper')
        .append($(document.createElement('div')).addClass('quantityTicker')
        .append('<input type="text" name="qty" id="quantity_wanted_' + idProduct + '" class="text ticker-input" value="1">')
        .append('<a href="#" data-field-qty="qty" class="btn btn-default button-minus product_quantity_down ticker-button ticker-down"><span><i class="icon-minus"></i></span></a>')
        .append('<a href="#" data-field-qty="qty" class="btn btn-default button-plus product_quantity_up ticker-button ticker-up"><span><i class="icon-plus"></i></span></a>')
    );
```

Нужно в value="1" вместо "1" добавить этот код PHP:

```
{if isset($quantityBackup)}{$quantityBackup|intval}{else}{if $product->minimal_quantity > 1}{$product->minimal_quantity}{else}1{/if}{/if}
```

Подскажите как правильно это сделать.
Спасибо!

вот весь файл скрипта (**модуля prestahop**):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var collection = $(tickerSelector);

if (collection.length > 0 && typeof(window.ajaxCart) == 'object') {
    ajaxCart.overrideButtonsInThePage = function(){
        $(document).off('click', '.ajax_add_to_cart_button').on('click', '.ajax_add_to_cart_button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var idProduct =  parseInt($(this).data('id-product'));
        var minimalQuantity =  parseInt($(this).data('minimal_quantity'));
        if (!minimalQuantity)
            minimalQuantity = 1;
        if ($(this).prop('disabled') != 'disabled')
            ajaxCart.add(idProduct, null, false, this, minimalQuantity);
    });
    //for product page 'add' button...
    $(document).off('click', '#add_to_cart button').on('click', '#add_to_cart button', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        ajaxCart.add($('#product_page_product_id').val(), $('#idCombination').val(), true, null, $('#quantity_wanted').attr('value'), null);
    });

        $('#cart_block_list .ajax_cart_block_remove_link').unbind('click').click(function(){
            var customizationId = 0;
            var productId = 0;
            var productAttributeId = 0;

            if ($($(this).parent().parent()).attr('name') == 'customization') {
                var customizableProductDiv = $($(this).parent().parent()).find("div[id^=deleteCustomizableProduct_]");
            }
            else {
                var customizableProductDiv = $($(this).parent()).find("div[id^=deleteCustomizableProduct_]");
            }

            if (customizableProductDiv && $(customizableProductDiv).length) {
                $(customizableProductDiv).each(function(){
                    var ids = $(this).attr('id').split('_');

                    if (typeof(ids[1]) != 'undefined') {
                        customizationId = parseInt(ids[1]);
                        productId = parseInt(ids[2]);

                        if (typeof(ids[3]) != 'undefined') {
                            productAttributeId = parseInt(ids[3]);
                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }

            if ( ! customizationId) {
                var firstCut = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id').replace('cart_block_product_', '');
                firstCut = firstCut.replace('deleteCustomizableProduct_', '');
                ids = firstCut.split('_');
                productId = parseInt(ids[0]);

                if (typeof(ids[1]) != 'undefined') {
                    productAttributeId = parseInt(ids[1]);
                }
            }

            ajaxCart.remove(productId, productAttributeId, customizationId);
            return false;
        });
    };

$(document).off('click', '.ajax_add_to_cart_button').on('click', '.ajax_add_to_cart_button', function(e){
    var idProduct =  $(this).data('id-product');
    ajaxCart.add(idProduct, null, false, this, parseInt($('#quantity_wanted_' + idProduct).attr('value')));
    return false;
});

$(document).on('click', '.ticker-button', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var parentDiv = $(this).parents('div.quantityTicker:first');

    if (parentDiv.length) {
        var thisInput = parentDiv.find('input.ticker-input'),
        thisVal = parseInt(thisInput.attr('value'));
        if (isNaN(thisVal)) {
            thisVal = 1;   
        }
        if ($(this).is('.ticker-up')) {
            thisVal++;
        }
        else if (thisVal > 1) {
            thisVal--;
        }
        thisInput.attr('value', thisVal);
    }
});

collection.each(function(){
    var idProduct =  $(this).data('id-product');

    var tickerContainer = $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('ticker-wrapper')
        .append($(document.createElement('div')).addClass('quantityTicker')
        .append('<input type="text" name="qty" id="quantity_wanted_' + idProduct + '" class="text ticker-input" value="1">')
        .append('<a href="#" data-field-qty="qty" class="btn btn-default button-minus product_quantity_down ticker-button ticker-down"><span><i class="icon-minus"></i></span></a>')
        .append('<a href="#" data-field-qty="qty" class="btn btn-default button-plus product_quantity_up ticker-button ticker-up"><span><i class="icon-plus"></i></span></a>')
    );

    tickerContainer.insertBefore($(this));

    var currentInput = tickerContainer.find('div.ticker-input-wrapper'),
    currentInputHeight = currentInput.outerHeight();

        //tickerContainer.find('div.ticker-button').css({'height': currentInputHeight + 'px'});
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

записать, конечно, можно, но это, вероятно, бессмысленно.

ведь, скорее всего, *javascript*-код в вашем случае выполняется *js*-интерперататором в браузере клиента.

но, во-первых, браузер клиента вряд ли будет выполнять код, написанный для интерпретатора *php*, а во-вторых, даже если (вдруг) и будет, у него (браузера) точно нет доступа к используемым на вашем сайте переменным, классам и всему прочему.

---

ваш вопрос приобретает смысл, только если приведённый *javascript*-код формируется интерпретатором *php* **внутри** вашего сайта.

тогда, например, можно использовать «обычную» *php*-вставку:

```
html-текст (в том числе и js-код) <?php здесь php-код ?> ещё html-текст
```

после обработки такого файла интерпретатором *php* вместо `<?php ... ?>` будет подставлен **резульат** работы *php*-кода.

Comment: обратите внимание на часть кода id="quantity_wanted_' + idProduct + '"  где ' + idProduct + ' как раз взят из PHP он добавляет ID в окончание, то есть нужный мне код нужно перевести в такой же синтаксис, а как это сделать не знаю, прошу у вас помощи.

Comment: @Стас, например, `print $переменная;` напишите внутри вставки `<?php ... ?>`.

Comment: не работает, пробовал

Comment: @Стас, значит, скорее всего, этот файл, в который вы всё это пытаетесь вставить, не формирует html-код интерпретатором *php*, а статически отдаётся http-сервером.

Comment: @Стас, проблема этого вопроса в том, что вы не описали никакой конкретики. что это за файл, который вы пытаетесь исправить, откуда он взялся, каким образом он обрабатывается http-сервером, и т.д. и т.п. / потому вам можно дать только какие-то общие абстрактные рекомендации.

Comment: @Стас, вот вы добавили **содержимое** некоего файла. но вы не понимаете, **что** у вас спрашивают. как называется этот файл, где вы его взяли, где он находится, как его содержимое попадает в браузер к клиенту? постарайтесь ответить хотя бы на часть этих вопросов. исходя из ответов можно будет либо задать вам уточняющие вопросы, либо уже дать конкретные рекомендации.

Comment: это файл модуля престашоп, который добавляет выбор количества товара в категориях, добавил к вопросу весь файл скрипта

Comment: @Стас, спасибо, про prestashop — уже какая-то конкретика. я лично не имею ни малейшего понятия, что это такое, поэтому, раз вы не можете рассказать иных подробностей, придётся  вам ждать «специалистов по prestashop-у».

Answer (score 1):

Если предположить, что js из первого блока находится в шаблоне, то код php (который в общем-то не php, а код для шаблона в Prestashop) можно поставить так:

```
        .append('<input type="text" name="qty" id="quantity_wanted_' + idProduct + '" class="text ticker-input" value="{if isset($quantityBackup)}{$quantityBackup|intval}{else}{if $product->minimal_quantity > 1}{$product->minimal_quantity}{else}1{/if}{/if}">')
```

Comment: Скрипт находится в отдельном файле, поэтому этот вариант не работает.

Comment: Сделайте поиск по подстроке "idProduct" в файлах шаблонов. Где-то эта переменная должна задаваться в виде "var idProduct =" или "idProduct =". И в этом js глянте. Если найдете, то код покажите тут.

Comment: добавил весь код файла JS

Comment: Переменная idProduct в js передается через html, Для этого используется атрибут data-id-product у объекта. Если там же, где задается этот атрибут в шаблоне в виде data-id-product="ТУТ КОМАНДА PHP" дописть data-quantity-value="{if isset($quantityBackup)}{$quantityBackup|intval}{else}{if $product->minimal_quantity > 1}{$product->minimal_quantity}{else}1{/if}{/if}" А в скрипт после var idProduct =  $(this).data('id-product'); добавить var quantityValue =  $(this).data('quantity-value'); и заменить value="1" на value="' + quantityValue + '" то может быть будет работать.

Comment: в том то и дело что этот атрибут в шаблон добавляет этот файл скрипта, посмотрите внизу код

Comment: Этот атрибут не добавляется скриптом js.

Comment: В шаблоне product.tpl например он введен через html: ... data-id-product="{$accessory.id_product|intval}" ... P.S. Извиняюсь, тут enter срабатывает на отправку сообщения сразу :(

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо! ответ нашел сам, оказалось все просто
Добавил переменную

```
var minimalQuantity =  parseInt($(this).data('minimal_quantity'));
```

и вывел ее value="' + minimalQuantity + '"